# Flutter - how to make nested list views?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a nested list view in the following manner

[image]

How can I do this? I only want the nested list view for one of the radio tiles not all of them.

I tried including both ListView builder in another List however there was rendering problem.

My code:

```
Column(

      children: <Widget>[
        .....

        Expanded(
          child:

          ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            itemCount: tasks.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

              return RadioListTile<String>(

               //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                title:  Text(tasks[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                value: tasks[index],
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                onChanged: (val){
                    setSelectedRadio(val);
                }
              );
            },
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid using third party services to show images. If you need to add images, add them to the post by either clicking the image button while editing, or copying the image and clicking CTRL+V, or in any other way pasting it) directly into the post. Third party image services [can break at any time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354950/6296561), and either leave a dead link, or the URLs can be used for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot build a `ListView` inside a `ListView` as you will confuse the scroll behaviour. You should use List widget that does not scroll, such as `Column`.

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  itemCount: tasks.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (// single RadioListTile) {
      return RadioListTile<String>(
        title:  Text(tasks[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
        value: tasks[index],
        groupValue: selectedRadio,
        onChanged: (val) => setSelectedRadio(val),
      );
    }
    else if (// nested RadioListTile) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // RadioListTile1,
          // RadioListTile2,
          // RadioListTile3,
        ],
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can totally include a list view inside of another list view. But the inside list view has to have shrinkWrap set to true